# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.application.descriptor.MungerLogger

Tags: weblogic12c

I am deploying in Weblogic but I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/application/descriptor/MungerLogger
     [java]     at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:823)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:413)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:779)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:792)
     [java]     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppDescriptor.getWebAppBean(WebAppDescriptor.java:142)
     [java]     at weblogic.servlet.jsp.jspc20.initDescriptors(jspc20.java:537)
     [java]     at weblogic.servlet.jsp.jspc20.runBody(jspc20.java:273)
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
     [java]     at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
     [java]     at weblogic.jspc.main(jspc.java:22)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.application.descriptor.MungerLogger
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
     [java]     ... 10 more
```

deploying with the free **Oracle WebLogic Server 12c (12.1.3)**
I have no idea from where I can get this class from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to download the jar which contains MungerLogger. In pom.xml add dependency:
        
            com.common
            jarName
            x.x

Then you need to tell Weblogic to load the jar which contains the MungerLogger. Add this script into weblogic.xml or weblogic-application.xml:

the package contain MungerLogger such as com.common.
        
        
            *the package contain MungerLogger such as com.common.*

Use this on top of weblogic.xml:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.2/weblogic-web-app.xsd">